# Backoffice : ClassificationAttributeValue visibility issue

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

**Hybris 6.3.0.2**

In ClassAttributeAssignment, user can changed the type to valueList so that he can show a pre-defined list of ClassificationAttributeValues in dropdown in product attribute tab for classificationAttribute.

Problem : The problem is very weird, as for some of classification attribute, value is not showing even though we are setting type as valuelist/enum and giving some classificationAttributeValues to feature descriptor values. Only na is showing, nothing else.

[image: The wh]

The whole pattern is random, for some of classification attribute, its working, for some of classification attribute, its not working. We are not able to identify why its happening because we match those attributes as well with one which is working with another which is not working. Both having same configuration but one of them its not showing.

In HMC, values are coming for all, but in Backoffice only its giving problem.

Can someone please guide us to fix this issue.

Comment: What is your version? Did you try synchronization? All attribute model are same? May be you can share export of these attributes.

Comment: @mkysoft its Hybris 6.3.0.2. Do you know how drop-down values are rending in backoffice. I can see FeatureValueEditor which is responsible for rending the value section which is being called from ClassificationTabEditorAreaRenderer. But i am not getting where exactly they are populating dropdown values.

Comment: Values are coming from populator. May be populator manipulate your features. Did you check json data which are coming from backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in FeatureEditor in the below line.

```
ClassificationAttributeModel attribute = assignment.getClassificationAttribute();
ClassificationClassModel cclass = (ClassificationClassModel)attribute.getClasses().iterator().next();
```

We extend FeatureEditor to override method and fetched ClassificationClassModel from ClassAttributeAssignmentModel instead of ClassificationAttributeModel .